# Use regex to filter out words that don't meet a criteria

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text 0 to 10,000+ words long in a single string. I also have an input string `input`. How can I remove all words in the string that do not begin with `input`?

Ex:

"This is a string containing thirty-trillion thirsty thespians."

input = "th"

I'd like "This thirty thirsty thespians" returned. I have little knowledge of regex so I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ has some good information about regular expressions if you're just getting started

Comment: @F.J javascript, sorry for leaving that out, and thank you CorrugatedAir!

Comment: How do you define a word? i.e. How would you split up the string into words?

Comment: Currently `.split(" ")` (to clarify, currently doing this action with arrays, but want to create a more efficient system with regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a perl solution, I hope that is of some help.

```
$beginning = "th";
$s = "This is a string containing thirty-trillion thirsty thespians."; 
@results = $s =~/\b($beginning\w*)/ig;
print for @results`
```

and it will print

> This thirty thirsty thespians

The regular expression does the following:
It starts its match with a word boundary, `\b`.
`($beginning\w*)` captures words that start with `$beginning` followed by zero or more
word characters. The brackets mean that it is to return whatever was matched inside of the brackets.

The `i` means that it is not case sensitive the `g` means that it goes through the whole string and returns everything that matches as a list (`@results` here).

Comment: Got it! Thanks a ton. For those interested I wound up with:`var re = new RegExp("\b(" + input + "\w*)", 'gi');`